# Convert SAS Compged function to Python

Tags: python, sas, levenshtein-distance, edit-distance

For project requirements, I am converting all the SAS codes to python, I got stuck where for 2 string matching, SAS inbuilt COMPGED function is used. I need the same score so need to convert it into Python code rather than using other libraries like fuzzywuzzy.

Please help if possible, just need some starter code to understand how to build it.

[COMPGED](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lefunctionsref&docsetTarget=p1r4l9jwgatggtn1ko81fyjys4s7.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en)

Answer (score 0):

Getting exact match is going to be extremely complex. You will need to produce your own implementation of the generalised edit distance.

A good starting point might be here:
https://www.python-course.eu/levenshtein_distance.php